# Upper and lower bounds of sequences whose product of terms is asymptotically equal to their arithmetic mean

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let  $ (c_n)_{n\geq 0} $ be a sequence of positive reals such that  $ \dfrac{1}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}c_{k}\sim\prod_{k=0}^{m-1} c_{k}$ as  $ m $ tends to infinity.
Call such a sequence a "corridor sequence" (as intuitively each of the terms should be "close to  $ 1 $).

Which upper bound can be given for the quantity  $ \sup_{k\leq m}\{c_{k}\}-\inf_{k\leq m}\{c_{k}\} $ provided the set of values of the corridor sequence is dense in some interval containing  $ 1 $ ?

Comment: Did you want an mth root?

Comment: No, I'm really thinking about sequences containing terms quite close to  $ 1 $. Without the density requirement a sequence like  $ 1/2, 2, 1, 1,1,... $  would do the job.

Comment: This question comes from math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750552/probability-of-m-to-be-a-primality-radius-of-n, where the sequence  $ c_{k} $ might be a corridor sequence.

Comment: By "some interval containing 1", do you mean an open interval? E.g., the interval [1,1] of length 0 is also an interval containing 1. Also, may some of the c_k's be outside that interval?

Comment: Yes, I mean an open interval, at least of Lebesgue measure different from  $ 0 $ . As for hypothetical values outside such an interval, I require only finitely many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\PP}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}}$

Let us also use a comment by the OP, stating that the interval (say $I$) in which the $c_k$'s are dense is of nonzero length and only finitely many $c_k$'s are outside of $I$.

Let us then show that such a sequence of $c_k$'s cannot exist (and so, any bound on  $\sup_{k\leq m}\{c_{k}\}-\inf_{k\leq m}\{c_{k}\} $ will be true). (The main idea here is that the consecutive arithmetic means may only vary very slowly, whereas the consecutive products may vary very fast.)

Indeed, suppose the contrary, that there is a sequence $(c_n)_{n\ge0}$ of positive reals such that  $$a_m:=\dfrac{1}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}c_{k}\sim\prod_{k=0}^{m-1} c_{k}=:b_m$$ 
as $m\to\infty$, the $c_k$'s are dense in an interval $I$ of nonzero length containing $1$, and only finitely many $c_k$'s are outside of $I$. Then there is some $\de\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$ such that $1+\de\in I$. Therefore and because the $c_k$'s are dense in $I$, 
\begin{equation*}
 c_m=(1+\de)(1+o(1)) \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
infinitely often (i.o.), that is, $c_{m_j}=(1+\de)(1+o(1))$ for some increasing sequence $(m_j)$ of natural numbers as $j\to\infty$. So, 
\begin{equation*}
 b_{m+1}=b_mc_m=b_m(1+\de)(1+o(1))=a_m(1+\de)(1+o(1)) \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
i.o. On the other hand,
\begin{equation*}
 a_{m+1}=\frac{m}{m+1}a_m+\frac{c_m}{m+1}=a_m(1+o(1))+\frac{c_m}{m+1}. \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
Since $b_{m+1}=a_{m+1}(1+o(1))$, (2) and (3) imply that i.o.
\begin{equation*}
 a_m(1+\de)(1+o(1))=a_m(1+o(1))+\frac{c_m}{m+1}, 
\end{equation*}
whence $a_m[(1+\de)(1+o(1))-(1+o(1))]=\frac{c_m}{m+1}\sim\frac{1+\de}m$ and 
\begin{equation*}
 a_m\sim\frac{1+\de}\de\,\frac1m. \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
Since $a_m>0$, it follows that necessarily $\de>0$, that is, $I\subseteq[1,\infty)$.

Since only finitely many $c_k$'s are outside of $I$, we see that the positive numbers $b_m$ are nondecreasing in all large enough $m$, and so, $b_m$ goes to some $b\in(0,\infty]$ as $m\to\infty$. But this contradicts (4), since $a_m\sim b_m$.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, the only possible way for a corridor sequence to exist is to allow the interval  $[1,1] $?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN : Yes, that is right. I have added a brief remark about the main idea of the proof: that the consecutive arithmetic means may only vary very slowly, whereas the consecutive products may vary very fast (if factors bounded away from $1$ are allowed).

Comment: I see. As far as the question on MSE is concerned, would it strongly suggest that the constant involved in  $ O(\log^{2}n) $ is  $ 1 $, as it should be equal to  $ 1/\inf_{k\leq m}\{c_{k}\} $?

Comment: Concerning that MSE question, I am not familiar enough with number theory to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, there is no bound for the difference between the largest and smallest of the first m members.

Suppose the product of the first m members is P, and their sum is S, and further that P is greater than 1/m.  There is a c readily found such that (m+1)cP = c + S, and now one can follow the mostly arbitrary first m members by c and then by a sequence which ensures the density property desired.  I suspect the wrong question was asked.

Gerhard "Lim Version May Be Harder" Paseman, 2018.04.26.