# probability of m to be a primality radius of n

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Disclaimer : this is a crosspost from MSE, as the question got one upvote but no comment or answer whatsoever.

Assuming Goldbach's conjecture, let's denote by  $r_{ 0}(n):=\inf\{r\geq 0,(n−r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\} $ . Then Cramer's model allows to write that the probability  $ P((n−k,n+k)\in\mathbb{P}^{2})=\dfrac{c_{k}}{\log^{2}n} $  and  $ r_{0}(n)=\inf\{m,\sum_{k=0}^{m}\dfrac{c_{k}}{log^{2}n}≥1\} $ .

I have two questions :

1) Would a proof that  $ \forall k, c_{k}>0 $ entail that  $ r_{0}(n)=O(\log^{2}n) $ ?

2) Building on the answer to [Upper and lower bounds of sequences whose product of terms is asymptotically equal to their arithmetic mean](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298784/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-sequences-whose-product-of-terms-is-asymptotically-equ), would an affirmative answer to 1) imply that the involved constant in  $ O(\log^{2}n) $ actually equals  $ 1 $?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes sense to focus on a particular $n.$  All that follows is speculative and depends on heuristics which are unproven yet widely believed to be true and well supported empirically.

One could discuss the distribution of $r_0(n)$ for large $n$ in some range and make strong predictions. But that would tell you nothing about possible outliers. It would be interesting to see how the distribution changes when restricted to those $n$ with a specified set of small odd prime divisors.

One could perhaps speculate on $$\limsup \frac{r_0(n)}{(\log{n})^2}.$$

---

The definition of $c_k$ is somewhat problematic.

One could, for each   $k>1$ look at $\pi_{2k}(x)=|\{2m \lt x \mid (2m-k,2m+k)\in \mathbb{P}\}|.$ Then one expects for each $k$ that there is a $c_k$ with  $$\pi_{2k}(x)\sim \frac{2c_kx}{(\log x)^2}$$ in the sense that the ratio goes to $1.$ Here $c_k$ depends only on the set of prime divisors of $k.$ I think $$c_k=\prod\left(1-\frac1{(p-1)^2}\right)$$ where the product ranges over the odd primes which are relatively prime to $k.$

So indeed $c_{2k} \gt 0$ for all $k$ and, further,  $c_{2k} \geq c_2 \approx 0.66$ with equality exactly when $k$ is a power of $2.$

Comment: Yes, maybe the problem comes from the fact that the numbers  $ c_{k} $ don't depend only on  $ k $  but also on  $ n $ .